# How to block users from viewing the .CSS

Tags: css

Well, as the title is saying. I am trying to block users from viewing my .CSS file, it's for now still on localhost because i need to script the whole CSS.

The web-directory link is web-content/app/css/wubbo.CSS, but i don't want users to view it but i want the web-page layout still showing. (I hate people who rip my layout.

Is there any possibility to do this? I run my webserver on IIS 8.0 with Coldfusion 10.

Comment: No. You can obfuscate it, but a browser must be able to retrieve it.

Comment: I am curious, why would you want to do this? Why does it matter?

Answer (score 9):

You cannot keep someone from viewing your CSS; however, you can *minify* your CSS which makes it harder to read, and gives you the added performance boost by shrinking the size of your CSS. I would recommend miniifying your code when deploying to your test and production environments, keeping your local and/or devlopment environments non-minified helps you debug your code quicker.

There are online tools that allow you to minify your CSS manually, or you can automate the process of minifying it with tools like [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) and [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/).

Comment: I second the use of grunt. It's a great tool that can easily be setup to minify/obfuscate all of your css and js files (obfuscation is for js only), plus tons of other cool stuff.

Comment: Just remember, minifying/obfuscating is of little use to any non-casual user who wants access to your code. In particular CSS is simply not complicated enough to make it very hard to unpack - just some _grunt_ work. :)

Comment: you can also use source maps, both in dev and production to help debug issues.